# How can I set the date of moment.js object to the server date when parsing MS ASP.NET JSON Date?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime, momentjs

**Note: Question was updated for clarity**

I have an application that is located on a server in EST. I'm using an MVC5 application with Entity Framework 6 and [jQuery DataTables](http://datatables.net) to display my index pages. I'm using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) to parse the .NET JSON Date.

The server is located in EST and the users are all on EST. However, whenever I render the date on the jQuery DataTable using the code below, I get the date plus twelve hours. (i.e. if on MS SQL Server the DATETIME field is '03/31/2015 00:00:00', it'll display '03/31/2015 12:00:00'.)

```
localOutput.Append(column.ColumnType == "DateTime" ? "\"render\": function( data, type, row ) { if (data) { return moment(data).zone(" + TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.UtcNow) + ").format(\"MM/DD/YYYY" + (column.Name == "Date" ? " hh:mm" : (column.Name == "Timestamp" ? " hh:mm:ss" : "")) + "\"); } else { return null; }}, " : "");
```

Originally, I asked how to get the UTC offset, thinking that the error was because it was converting from UTC to local time and adding the difference. However, EST is only -5 from UTC, not +12 hours. I've tried changing the zone in moment.js by using the code above and it just returns an odd number. Some would be '03/31/2015 04:00:00' and others would be '03/31/2015 05:00:00'.

I am at a loss right now for how to resolve this. I tried taking the easy way and just subtracting 12 hours from the date, but that returns '03/31/2015 04:00:00', which is only 8 hours subtracted.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this properly? What am I missing here?

Comment: will this work? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.getutcoffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I tried using it, but it's not listed as a known method of the TimeZone class. I'm referencing System like the documentation says. So, I'm really not sure.

Comment: Some time zone offsets are not whole numbers of hours: [List of tz database time zones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe I found the answer to my problem, and it had nothing to do with the timezone whatsoever.

In my code, I was formatting the message date using moment.js to display as `"MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm"` because we only needed that much accuracy and wanted to save space on the column by not displaying seconds and "AM:PM." However, I was not setting it to use military time. Therefore, it was displaying the "12:00" portion of "12:00:00 AM", NOT referring to 12:00 hours in military time as I thought it was. That's why even if I subtracted 12 hours, it would still display 12 and when I subtracted the appropriate EST offset, it would display 8:00PM or 7:00PM (depending on DST).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TotalHours` propery of `TimeSpan` class which is returend by `TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.UtcNow)`